# Adding multiple dynamic series and axes via JSON into Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Like many Highstock users, our data is retrieved from a database by way of Ajax queries. The series data sets are all time-based, but have different purposes and data ranges.

I can add multiple series to the chart no problem. Works great. However, how can I *dynamically* (emphasis on dynamically) add companion axes to these series (axis title and range)? I've scoured the documentation and forums but can't figure out exactly how to associate the *new* axis with the *new* series.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your attempts ? A fiddle would be helpful and narrow down the query.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this (as far as I know) is to add multiple empty axes to your chart, and then set them programmatically. It's a hack - but it works:

http://livecoding.io/3431916